# How to remove MySql bin logs automatically when slave completed sync ?

Tags: mysql, linux

**I have two mysql servers one is mater(mysqlone) and another is slave(mysql2) have replication**
**i want to delete log file automatically in master when slave completes the reading of logs from  
master, without script is there any options and variables in mysql**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple answer - No. You`ll have to make/get something if you want it automated.

Are you aware of [PURGE BINARY LOGS](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/purge-binary-logs.html)?

It is not too difficult to automate this using a script.

Comment: i will check PURGE BINARY LOGS,thanks a lot,but ok i will try